# How to compress ecw when gdal_translate from tiff to ecw?

Tags: raster, gdal, geotiff-tiff, ecw

I wish to translate geotiff 16gb to ecw, cause current size is so big. but when I run

```
 sudo gdal_translate  ppp_2020.tif ppp_compr.ecw -co "COMPRESSION_RATE_TARGET =80"
0...70...80...90...100 - done.
```

I have .ecw = 84 gb!!!

terminal throws this:

```
Input file size is 432000, 48803
Warning 6: driver GTiff does not support creation option COMPRESSION_RATE_TARGET 
0...10...20...30...40...50...6
```

How to compress target ecw from geotiff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Warning 6: driver GTiff does not support creation option COMPRESSION_RATE_TARGET` suggests that it's not writing an ECW, it's writing a TIFF despite the file having an .ecw extension.  Use `-of` to control the [output format](https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/index.html).

Note that ECW is a proprietary format that requires licensing to be able to write, so if you haven't purchased that and recompiled GDAL to use it then you're out of luck.

Comment: Version 3.x of the ECW SDK license does allow writing if the input image is not bigger than 300 MB. That version was pretty buggy but because of R/W support it is still available in some GDAL builds. I do not recommend to use it really.